# How to force Centos to use ipv6 interface only?

Tags: networking, centos, openvpn, ipv6, ipv4

My Centos server has two virtual (Openvz) interfaces. One from these interfaces has ipv4 address configured, while the other one has the ipv6 one. In short this server is used for browsing / proxy.

**Browsing scenarios**

- Case 1:

  ssh tunnel + tinyproxy = visited web pages detect that client has **ipv6** address
- Case 2:

  OpenVPN (tcp proto) = visited web pages detect that client has **ipv4** address

**Question**

Is it possible to configure OpenVPN (or the OS) like in the first case - to be visible as a ipv6-based host during the browsing?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to remove IPv4 from the second interface but the only way to **completely** disable IPv4 is to disable it at the kernel level.

Comment: How the first case is even possible?